# is having login sessions in winforms appropriate?

Tags: c#, winforms, session, authentication

I cannot find tutorials on making login sessions anywhere on winforms. These few months I watched a video tutorial that is making a login system with sessions but it is in web, using php. Is it only applicable on web? Please enlighten me.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? what do you mean by login session? - its a broad question.

Comment: I am talking about when you log in, you get a new entry of session ID that is generated, it also logs your time of login and everything related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jwt to create token and set expiration for token.my suggestion is that validate token in form load or constructor and if it expire redirect user to login form or any where you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info! This should do it.

Comment: I just created my account so it wont show publicly that I upped your answer. But I already upped it :)